# Bluetooth headset has choppy audio playback and lags

Tags: bluetooth, headset, wireless-headset

I recently got a bluetooth headset, a BTH002, for testing purposes.
It uses Bluetooth v 2.1.

I bought a bluetooth adapter to use with it, a Trust BT-2400p. it has Bluetooth version 3.0. The adapter is plugged into a USB 2.0 port.

Everything installed fine, but the audio playback is really choppy and when watching a video I can hear that the audio lags behind quite a bit. When starting a Skype call the audio quality is lowered so that if I play music in the background I can clearly hear that the sound quality is, in lack of a better word, crappy.

The distance between the bluetooth adapter and the headset is never farther than 1 meter.
The battery is not low, otherwise it would complain by emitting a small beep.

I am pretty new to this technology and don't know what to expect from a bluetooth headset. Is there anything I could try to improve the audio quality?

Answer (score 0):

People still view this question, so maybe my solution works for others too.

I only care about playback, not the mic.

In Windows 10, all I had to do was open Device Manager (Just click Start and start typing "Device Manager", find Audio inputs and outputs.

My headphones were listed there three times: 1x Headphones (... Headphones Stereo), 2x ... Headphones Hands-Free.

I disabled both Hands-Free devices, and my issue was fixed.